# Libnodave: connectPLC returns -1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plc, libnodave

I'm trying to connect to a Siemens CPU315-2 DP via Ethernet by a CP 343-1 Lean using Libnodave dll.

I've tried the example program "simpleISO_TCP.cs" contained in the download file. The function openSocket works just fine but the function connectPLC always returns -1 wich
means that the connection to the PLC fails.

Anyone knows what could cause this problem?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things for you to check:

- Is the correct hardware configuration downloaded to the PLC
- Can you ping PLC IP Address
- If Simatic is installed have you disabled Port 102 service
- Is your rack and slot number correct

I would try to use the testISO_TCP.exe located in the win folder.  Run it from 
cmd prompt with IP Address and -w flag which will write to some memory addresses(ensure
that it safe to do this if it is a production PLC)

I was just doing some work with this library and it was fine using a CPU 317-2 PN/DP with a CP343-1 (6GK7 343-1EX11-0EX0)