# Multiple connections to CP 343-1 with LibNoDave

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plc, libnodave

I want to make several connections to a CPU 315-2 DP with a CP 343-1 module. Within the software I can make one connection to the device, but the second connections fails to connect and returns -1 in the function connectPLC.

A similar question is asked here: [Libnodave: connectPLC returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247313/libnodave-connectplc-returns-1), but I can make one connection but not a second.

In the same network there are two other CPU 315-2 PN/DP PLC's and we can make several connections to those PLC's.

I use Visual Studion 2010 with C#, and I use LibNoDave to connect to the PLC(s). Can someone tell me if I can make more than one connection to a CPU 315-2 DP with a CP 343-1 module?

Answer (score 0):

The CP343-1 is also called the LEAN ethernet card. First result in a google search is the following document:
http://cache.automation.siemens.com/dnl/zE/zEzMzUyOQAA_19308657_HB/mn_cp343-1-lean_76.pdf

In chapter 5.1 it gives the maximum number of connections as 12.

Comment: Only we use not the same unit, ours is a twice the size (http://cache.automation.siemens.com/dnl/zY/zYzMDc1AAAA_8777308_HB/ghb3431_e.pdf)

It can handle at maximum 16 connection. LibNoDave uses a PG connection via ISO-on-TCP. We see that connection get used and a second connection is rejected.

In some LibNoDave topics I see that it is possible to change the used connection type, but it is only possible within the C code.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make more than one connection to a PLC with a LEAN ethernet card with LibNoDave?